# Specify Elasticsearch aggregation fields when finding duplicates

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am using the following ES query when looking for duplicates:

```
"aggs": {
    "duplicates": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "phone",
            "min_doc_count": 2,
            "size": 99999,
            "order": {
                "_term": "asc"
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "_docs": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "size": 99999
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works well, it returns the key which in this case is the `phone`, and inside of it it returns all the matches. The main problem is exactly that, on the _source it brings everything, which is a lot of fields on my case, and I wanted to specify to bring only the ones I need. Example of what's returning:

```
        "duplicates": {
                "1": {
                    "key": "1",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "_docs": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": 2,
                            "max_score": 1,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "local:company_id:1:sync",
                                    "_type": "leads",
                                    "_id": "23",
                                    "_score": 1,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "id": 23,
                                        "phone": 123456,
                                        "areacode_id": 426,
                                        "areacode_state_id": 2,
                                        "firstName": "Brayan",
                                        "lastName": "Rastelli",
                                        "state": "", // .... and so on
```

I want to specify the fields that will be returned on the `_source`, is that possible?

Another problem that I'm having is that I want to order the aggregation results by a specific field (by `id`) but if I put any field name instead of `_term` it gives me an error.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the below example, documents with `id` `29` and `23` have the same `phone`, hence these are duplicates. The search query will show only two fields i.e `id` and `phone` (you can change these fields according to your condition) and sort the top hits result on the basis of `id`

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "id": 29,
  "phone": 123456,
  "areacode_id": 426,
  "areacode_state_id": 2,
  "firstName": "Brayan",
  "lastName": "Rastelli",
  "state": ""
}
{
  "id": 23,
  "phone": 123456,
  "areacode_id": 426,
  "areacode_state_id": 2,
  "firstName": "Brayan",
  "lastName": "Rastelli",
  "state": ""
}
{
  "id": 30,
  "phone": 1235,
  "areacode_id": 92,
  "areacode_state_id": 10,
  "firstName": "Mark",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "state": ""
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicates": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "phone",
        "min_doc_count": 2,
        "size": 99999
      },
      "aggs": {
        "_docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "phone",
                "id"
              ]
            },
            "sort": [
              {
                "id": {
                  "order": "asc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "duplicates": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 123456,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "_docs": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": null,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "66896259",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_score": null,
                  "_source": {
                    "phone": 123456,
                    "id": 23
                  },
                  "sort": [
                    23                       // note this
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "_index": "66896259",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "2",
                  "_score": null,
                  "_source": {
                    "phone": 123456,
                    "id": 29
                  },
                  "sort": [
                    29                         // note this
                  ] 
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```